# How to use wildcards / operators in javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is my code :

```
if(status == "*Contacted*")
        {
            jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('setRowData',rows[i],false, {  color:'black',weightfont:'bold',background:'yellow'});            
        }
```

I want the "*" to act like a wildcard, so that if it finds a string like :

Contacted,Scheduled

it will still execute the code.  Am I using the wildcard incorrectly - because the way I have it, the code only works if the string is simply "Contacted" with nothing else mixed in

I am also having an issue with operators, for instance the following code will not work for me :

```
if(status == "Contacted" || "Scheduled")
        {
          whatever here           
        }
```

I actually have to write it like this to make it work :

```
 if(status == "Contacted")
                {
                  whatever here           
                }
    if(status == "Scheduled")
                {
                  whatever here           
                }
```

I don't know why a simple or operator does not function.

Comment: Use `status.includes('Contacted')`

Comment: Looks like you want a regex match, rather than equality.

Comment: With the edit it looks like you've confused how that operator works. `status == "Contacted" || status == "Scheduled"` would also work just fine.

Comment: `/\bContacted\b/i.test(status)` will be true if the whole word in any case exists.

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe for helping me with the operator, that was exactly what I was trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`String#includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) for that :

> `String#includes` returns `true` if its first parameter is found
>   anywhere within the given string; otherwise, `false` if not.

```
if(status.includes("Contacted")){
    jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('setRowData',rows[i],false, {  color:'black',weightfont:'bold',background:'yellow'});            
}
```

Comment: Is there a String#doesnotinclude operator?

Comment: @Steven You can simply add a `!` before `status.includes("Contacted")`, it will reverse the boolean.

Comment: like such?
if(!status.includes("Contacted")){

Comment: @Steven Yes, exactly.